# Database Configuration Assistant failed while installing oracle 12c on windows 10

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I tried installing oracle database 12c but it fails to install the database configuration assistant. Later while creating database manually this error appears. the image is attached .
[Error popup while creating database manually using dbca](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H0uh.png)

Comment: See the mentioned log files for further details. Also, post your error message as text, orhterwise it cannot be found via the search function.

Comment: I cannot find anything in the log file. i have tried everything but everytime i try creating the database this error appears
Error while executing "E:app\Saira1\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\rdbms\admin\dbmssml.sql".Refer to "E:\app\Saira1\cfgtoollogs\dbca\OracleDB\dbmssml0.log" for more details. Error in Process: E:\app\Saira1\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\per\bin\perl.exe

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting us to be able to do, when we can't see the log, or anything about your setup. This is off-topic anyway.

Comment: you may find this useful http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/Windows_DB_Install_OBE/Installing_Oracle_Db12c_Windows.html

Comment: Alex i am tring to install oracle database 12c on windows 10. while installing the setup it gives the error i mentioned earlier and it fails to confiugre the database configuration assistant. later when i try to create databse using dbca manually. again this error appears. and the log file is empty.

Comment: this is the best tutorial on installing these oracle apps that I have found :

http://10minutecode.blogspot.com/2018/03/installing-oracle-forms-and-reports-12c.html?q=install+oracle+forms+reports+12